# HttpClient not storing cookies in CookieContainer

Tags: c#, cookies, httpclient

I'm using `VS2010` +`.NET 4.0` + `System.Net.Http` (from `Nuget`).

For a reason which I don't manage to understand, the session cookie which I receive in my `HttpResponseMessage` is not automatically saved in the `HttpClient CookieContainer`. 
Here is what my code looks like:

```
CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();
HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.CookieContainer = cookies;
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);

Uri site = new Uri("https://www.mywebsite.com");
var response1 = client.SendAsync(new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get,site)).Result;
```

I can see in the response headers that I have the following:

```
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=FC8110E434C2C6DAB78B4E335024A639; Path=/member; Secure
```

However my cookie container remains empty ...why ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I guess the problem is that your cookies are *secure*. The problem is that, CookieContainer won't send secure cookies back to the server in subsequent HTTP requests. It might be a bug, or maybe it has some reasons behind it.

A workaround is to re-add the cookie to CookieContainer manually. This way, cookie would be sent back in HTTP request header, as no *secure* would be defined when you send cookies back to the server.

See [this article](http://thomaskrehbiel.com/post/1690-cookiecontainer_httpwebrequest_and_secure_cookies) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and the link, Saeed !
In my case, I just ended up reconfigure my HttpClientHandler as cookieless (hander.UseCookies = false), so that the session-id cookie just needs to be sent as a URL parameter to the web server)

Comment: @user2038596 - Secure cookies are only sent over secure channels such as HTTPS. See [RFC6265 §4.1.2.5](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6265#section-4.1.2.5) for details.

Comment: I experienced this problem even though the cookie was not secure, I also ruled out the HttpOnly property causing this behaviour.  Adding it back into the collection worked in my case as well.

Answer (score 19):

Use this piece of code to retrieve cookies from response:

```
/// <summary>
/// Read web cookies
/// </summary>
public static CookieContainer ReadCookies(this HttpResponseMessage response)
{
    var pageUri = response.RequestMessage.RequestUri;

    var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    IEnumerable<string> cookies;
    if (response.Headers.TryGetValues("set-cookie", out cookies))
    {
        foreach (var c in cookies)
        {
            cookieContainer.SetCookies(pageUri, c);
        }
    }

    return cookieContainer;
}
```

Comment: This only sets the first cookie. The `SetCookies(Uri, String)` method should only be called once with all cookie values delimited with commas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32956693/cookiecontainer-setcookies-only-sets-the-first-one

Answer (score 1):

I had problem with cookies because of case difference in path. I logged in to /mysite/login, and set cookie for mysite, but then redirect to /MySite, and HttpClient suddenly discard all the cookies! When I changed adress to /MySite/login all become ok.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the problem is that your request Url path is to the root of the web site ("/"), but your Set-Cookie header indicates a Path of "/member".

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are automatically decompressing the response:

```cs
HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler()
{
    AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate
};
```

Example:

```cs
var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
var clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler {
    AllowAutoRedirect = true,
    UseCookies = true,
    CookieContainer = cookieContainer,
    AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate,
};

var httpClient = new HttpClient(clientHandler);

var httpRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://example.com/");

var response = httpClient.Send(httpRequest);

response.Headers.TryGetValues("set-cookie", out var cookies);

string test = (new StreamReader(response.Content.ReadAsStream()).ReadToEnd());
```

## *Edit*

This also populates my `cookieContainer` automatically.  On both a `httpClient.GetAsync("https://example.com/")` or `SendAsync(httpRequest)`