# HttpClient Not Saving Cookies

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

I am using the new HttpClient to handle my project's web surfing needs; However, although correctly set, the HttpClient does not save the cookies to the Cookie container and it is always EMPTY.

#### Code

```
private CookieContainer _cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
private HttpClient HttpClient { get; set; }
private HttpClientHandler HttpClientHandler { get; set; }

public Initialize()
{
    HttpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler
                            {
                                AllowAutoRedirect = true,
                                UseCookies = true,
                                CookieContainer = _cookieContainer
                            };
    HttpClient = new HttpClient(HttpClientHandler);
}

public CookieContainer Cookies
{
    get { return _cookieContainer; }
    set { _cookieContainer = value; }
}

public void TEST()
{
    //This is always empty, although I am sure that the site is saving login cookies
    var cookies = Cookies;
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Weird... Did you tried to directly use the HttpClientHandler's CookieContainer ?

Code :

```
public Initialize()
{
    HttpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler
                            {
                                AllowAutoRedirect = true,
                                UseCookies = true,
                                CookieContainer = new CookieContainer()
                            };
    HttpClient = new HttpClient(HttpClientHandler);
}

public CookieContainer Cookies
{
    get { return HttpClientHandler.CookieContainer; }
    set { HttpClientHandler.CookieContainer = value; }
}
```

Comment: I know this is old code but note that HttpClientHandler.CookieContainer no longer works. You get an error saying that "An object reference is required for the non-static fields, ...". Clearly no longer a static object.

Comment: @Thierry: OP is declaring a `static HttpClientHandler HttpClientHandler` and a `static HttpClient HttpClient` .

Answer (score 0):

You may also need to decompress your response automatically.  See my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74750572/1158313

An example of what I use:

```cs
var clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler {
    AllowAutoRedirect = true,
    UseCookies = true,
    CookieContainer = cookieContainer,
    AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate,
};
```