# How to get response cookies using System.Net.Http.HttpClient?

Tags: dotnet-httpclient

This question has been asked a few times before, but I could not find a definite answer. Is it even possible to get response cookies using System.Net.Http.HttpClient?

Comment: Have you looked in the CookieContainer as described by this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17983992/httpclient-not-saving-cookies ?

Comment: Yes, I have, as well as a few other posts. None of them show how to get cookies from the response.

Answer (score 6):

Below is some sample code I have used for accessing server generated cookies.  I just tested it and it worked for me. I changed the credentials though.  If you want to see it working you will need to create yourself a nerddinner account.

```
    [Fact]
    public async Task Accessing_resource_secured_by_cookie()
    {
        var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
        var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);

        Assert.Equal(0, handler.CookieContainer.Count);

        // Create a login form
        var body = new Dictionary<string, string>() 
        {
            {"UserName",  "<username>"},
            {"Password", "<password>"},
            {"RememberMe", "false"}
        };
        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(body);

        // POST to login form
        var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("http://www.nerddinner.com/Account/LogOn?returnUrl=%2F", content);

        // Check the cookies created by server
        Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode);
        Assert.Equal(1, handler.CookieContainer.Count);
        var cookies = handler.CookieContainer.GetCookies(new Uri("http://www.nerddinner.com"));
        Assert.Equal(".ASPXAUTH", cookies[0].Name);

        // Make new request to secured resource
        var myresponse = await httpClient.GetAsync("http://www.nerddinner.com/Dinners/My");

        var stringContent = await myresponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.OK, myresponse.StatusCode);
    }
```

As you can see from the code, you don't get response cookies directly from the HTTP Response message.  I suspect the HttpClientHandler strips the header off the response before returning it.  However, the cookies from the response are placed in the CookieContainer and you can access them from there.

Comment: Does not work for me. The same request made with HttpWebRequest returns three cookies, while HttpClient returns only 1. May it have anything to do with the cookie type? The cookies that HttpClient does not return are FedAuth and FetAuth1 cookies produced by FederatedAuthentication ASP.NET MVC module.

Comment: @AlexI When you say "HttpClient returns only 1" do you mean that in the HttpResponseMessage Headers there is only 1 cookie, or do you mean that the CookieContainer only contains 1?  If you mean the latter, then I'm confused because under the covers, HttpClient uses the exact same code as HttpWebRequest/HttpWebResponse.

Answer (score 2):

to get a response cookie you can use this method;

```
private async Task<string> GetCookieValue(string url, string cookieName)
{
    var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    var uri = new Uri(url);
    using (var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler
    {
        CookieContainer = cookieContainer
    })
    {
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler))
        {
            await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);
            var cookie = cookieContainer.GetCookies(uri).Cast<Cookie>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == cookieName);
            return cookie?.Value;
        }
    }
}
```