# Download HTML from a ddos-protected site

Tags: c#, html

I'm trying to download the HTML-String of a page, which has an build in DDOS-denier: On the first access to the page, you have to wait 5 Seconds until you get redirected. The URL itself doesn't change, it seems just to be kindahow build in this URL.
Since I don't want to ddos anyway, I'd be fine to wait for 5 seconds, but I can't make it work to get the HTML after.
My try is looking like this at the moment (With some testing stuff):

```
    private async Task<string> GetRawHtmlAsync(HttpClientHandler handler, string threadUrl)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpResponseMessage resp = null;
            var client = new HttpClient(handler);

            resp = await client.GetAsync(threadUrl);
            var result = await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            if (result.Contains("This process is automatic. Your browser will redirect to your requested content shortly."))
            {
                return await GetRawHtmlAsync(handler, threadUrl);
            }

            return result;
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            using (var sr = new StreamReader(ex.Response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                var tra = ex.Response.ResponseUri;
                var tra2 = ex.Response.Headers.Get("Location");

                var html = sr.ReadToEnd();
                Debug.Write(html);
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

The HttpClientHandler is created via Factory:

```
    internal HttpClientHandler Create()
    {
        var handler = new HttpClientHandler()
        {
            AllowAutoRedirect = true,
            CookieContainer = new CookieContainer()
        };

        return handler;
    }
```

As you can see, I tried to tinker around wih the Cookies, described here: [HttpClient Not Saving Cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17983992/httpclient-not-saving-cookies). I also tried this approach: http://blog.project-sierra.de/archives/2132 but since there, is no redirect-URL, this doesn't work as well.

Is there a possibility to kindahow wait the 5 seconds out?

Edit: The window is looking like this, not sure if this helps:
[image]

Comment: This seems to me like you are trying to circumvent something that these folks put in place to prevent you from doing what you're attempting to do.

Comment: "I can't make it work" What isn't working? Are you getting an error? What error? Please read [ask] and how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Are you sure your `kindahow` website isn't using AJAX calls in JavaScript to populate the rest of the site after five seconds? Because this doesn't sound like DDoS protection to me.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan: "Is there a possibility to kindahow wait the 5 seconds out?" Seems a pretty straightforward question to me, no?