# HttpClient Post To Authorized Role Attributed Action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api, asp.net-web-api

How can I post/get from mvc action which is attributed with

`[Authorize(Roles = "Admin,Supervisor")]` ?

This is my action:

```
[AcceptVerbs("Get", "Post")]
[Authorize(Roles = "Operator,Supervisor")]
public string SortManageStocks(string sorter = "StockId", bool isAscending = false, string searchString = "", int currentPage = 1, int itemsPerPage = 50, bool showAll = false)
{
    StockViewModel viewModel = new StockViewModel();
    try
    {
    ...............
```

Which is running fine when I called it through mvc manners like:

```
string result = SortManageStocks(sorter, isAscending, searchString, currentPage, itemsPerPage, showAll);
```

How can I post/get to this action using httpclient method?

This is what I tried:

```
try
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var values = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

        // add values to data for post
        values.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("sorter", "StockId"));
        values.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("isAscending", "false"));
        values.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("searchString", ""));
        values.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("currentPage", "1"));
        values.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("itemsPerPage", "50"));
        values.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("showAll", "true"));

        FormUrlEncodedContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

        var result = client.PostAsync("http://localhost:50904/Operator/SortManageStocks", content).Result;
        var response = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

        if (result.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
        {
            var z = "Not authorized";
        }
    }
}
```

How can I pass the authorize(roles="") attribute with the httpclient?

Comment: You can't. You need to login, and then pass the relevant cookie/access token to the server with the request.

Comment: Can you show me how to do it? Thank you

Comment: How do you login to your API?

Comment: I only know how to login from the website, by using the `WebSecurity.Login(userName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe)`. I do not really have the function to login from API. I need help to create one. Thank you

Comment: You need to configure the _server_ to support login if you haven't already, and then use the appropriate login method in the client. I can't just give you an answer because, for example, one of our APIs uses OAuth for login, another API (our admin API) only allows login through Google, but both use Bearer tokens (sent in the Authorization header). Our old website used cookies instead of tokens, so that was different again. If you already have login working, try to mimic the client login requests using HttpClient.

Comment: Yes that is true. My problem is I use the simple membership login. The Login() function only returns cookies, it does not give the token in the return value. That is why it is gonna be difficult if I login from mobile devices that use application to interact with it. How can I get the auth token from mobile apps?

Comment: Hi Alvin, you should see the code in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17983992/httpclient-not-saving-cookies) for using cookies with `HttpClient`. Simply create one HttpClient as described, make a login request, and then make the request you're trying above.