# CookieContainer.SetCookies only sets the first one

Tags: c#

According to MSDN `CookieContainer.SetCookies` should

> Adds Cookie instances for one or more cookies from an HTTP cookie
>   header to the CookieContainer for a specific URI

which implies that it should work for multiple cookies, but when I do

```
_cookieContainer.SetCookies(new Uri("http://localhost"), "a=a;b=b");
```

and later try to retrieve the cookies using

```
_cookieContainer.GetCookies(new Uri("http://localhost"));
```

I only get one cookie entry which is `a=a`

I thought it might be that the cookie header format is wrong, so I manually added two cookies using `.Add` method, and later try to get the header by calling `.GetCookieHeader` , I get exactly the same string `"a=a;b=b"`.

Did I miss anything or did I just find a .NET bug? I am currently using

> VS2015 - v14.0.23107.0,
>   .NET - 4.6 4.6.00081

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why don't you try to pass the second parameter the same way as MSDN suggests on the documentation site of `SetCookies`:

> cookieHeader
>
> Type: System.String
>
> The contents of an HTTP set-cookie header as returned by a HTTP server, with Cookie instances delimited by **commas**.

```
_cookieContainer.SetCookies(new Uri("http://localhost"), "a=a,b=b");
```

Comment: @Steve Happens to everybody every once in a while :-)

Comment: Any idea why it's a comma although the HTTP header uses semicolons?

Comment: May be because each "set-cookie" header may contain meta data separated by semicolon: set-cookie: session-id=144-7242129-2595520; path=/; domain=.blahblahlbah.com; expires=Tue, 01-Jan-2025 06:00:01 GMT
set-cookie: session-id-datetime=2082787201l; path=/; domain=.blahblahlbah.com; expires=Tue, 01-Jan-2025 06:00:01 GMT

Answer (score 2):

You're using semicolons to delimit your cookies, but the [MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.cookiecontainer.setcookies(v=vs.110).aspx) state:

> SetCookies pulls all the HTTP cookies out of the HTTP cookie header, builds a Cookie for each one, and then adds each Cookie to the internal CookieCollection that is associated with the URI. **The HTTP cookies in the *cookieHeader* string must be delimited by commas.**

(emphasis added)