# .NET C# HttpClient read mutiple headers with same name

Tags: c#, http-headers, dotnet-httpclient

I'm making a request to a third party web service that I have no control over.
The request provides a number of authentication components that come back as Headers named `Set-Cookie`

However the `HttpResponseMessage.Headers` collection only contains a single entry named `Set-Cookie`

How can I access the others?

Example of response headers:

```
Set-Cookie: username=*********; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=Strict;SameSite=Lax
Set-Cookie: cust_id=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; Max-Age=0; SameSite=Strict; SameSite=Lax
Set-Cookie: auth_key=*************; expires=Mon, 23-Aug-2021 10:14:45 GMT; Max-Age=3600; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=Strict; SameSite=Lax
Set-Cookie: ws_key=*************; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=Strict; SameSite=Lax
Set-Cookie: ws_root=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; Max-Age=0; secure; SameSite=Strict; SameSite=Lax
Set-Cookie: impersonator=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; Max-Age=0; secure; SameSite=Strict; SameSite=Lax
```

The only one of the above which the `Headers` collection contains is:

```
auth_key=*************; expires=Mon, 23-Aug-2021 11:59:55 GMT; Max-Age=3600; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=Strict; SameSite=Lax
```

Comment: Headers are generally a set of key/value pairs.  Usually there are only 1 set, but the documentation does allow for multiples.

Comment: Either use [`TryGetValues`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.headers.httpheaders.trygetvalues?view=net-5.0#System_Net_Http_Headers_HttpHeaders_TryGetValues_System_String_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_String___) or set a `CookieCollection` on the handler and use that.

Comment: @LLama Thanks - tried both of those and neither of them work. `TryGetValues` only gets 1, and `CookieCollection` has 4, but are not retrievable.... maybe because they are secure, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14681144/httpclient-not-storing-cookies-in-cookiecontainer

Comment: @Morvael The `Headers` property 's type is `HttpHeaders`. That class implements the `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<String,IEnumerable<String>>>`. Have you tried to iterate through it with double foreach?